# Stored procedure parameters using tsql functions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Environment sql server 2005 sp3

I have a stored proc that takes an INT as input. I want to CAST a CHAR to an INT during the call to the stored proc. it seems I cannot do that. I get a syntax error before @foo. I do not see it can someone help me find it please. Thank you very much.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testme
@test AS INT
AS
BEGIN
SELECT @TEST
END

    DECLARE @foo AS CHAR(6)
set @foo = '11test'
EXEC testMe @test = CAST(Substring(@foo,1,2) as int)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SQL Rockstar's answer is how to fix it: I'll add an explanation.

A stored procedure parameter can be either a constant or variable: not an expression. CAST is an expression. (This is different to udf parameters that can accept expressions)

[EXEC on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) states

> ... @parameter = ] { value 
>                              | @variable [ OUTPUT ] 
>                              | [ DEFAULT ] 
>                              }

Answer (score 10):

Why not do the CAST when you SET @foo instead?

```
SET @foo = CAST(Substring('11test',1,2) as int)
```

You could even use a second variable and do this:

```
SET @foo1 = '11test'
SET @foo2 = CAST(Substring(@foo1,1,2) as int)
```

and then just call the proc:

```
EXEC testMe @test = @foo2
```